# Query to find products with all the given attributes

Tags: mysql, subquery, eav

I have a table in mySQL to store product attributes like this:

```
------------------------------------
| product_id | att_val1 | att_val2 |
------------------------------------
| 1001001    | x202     | 2200     |
| 1001002    | t100     | 180000   |
| 1001003    | T100     | 1080     |
| 1001001    | T100     | 700      |
| 1001005    | SS120    | 1080     |
| 1001001    | SS120    | 1080     |
| 1001004    | SS120    | 1080     |
```

I want to get all `product_id`s that have all the asked properties, I came up with this query

```
SELECT product_id FROM product_attributes 
WHERE product_id EXISTS (SELECT product_id from product_attributes WHERE att_val1 = 'x202' AND att_val2 = '2200')
AND product_id EXISTS (SELECT product_id from product_attributes WHERE att_val1 = 'SS120' AND att_val2 = '1080')
```

Is there a better way to achieve this result?

**UPDATED** (better sample)

I'm going to change the sample data to string values for better clarification

```
-------------------------------------------
|  product_id  |  attribute  |  value     |
-------------------------------------------
| iPhone 6s    | Screen Size | 4.7        |
| iPhone 7     | Screen Size | 4.7        |
| iPhone 8     | Screen Size | 4.7        |
| iPhone 6s    | Storage     | 64GB       |
| iPhone 7     | Storage     | 128GB      |
| iPhone 8     | Storage     | 64GB       |
| iPhone 6s    | NFC         | FALSE      |
| iPhone 7     | NFC         | FALSE      |
| iPhone 8     | NFC         | TRUE       |
```

I want to get the iPhone 8 which has `Screen Size = 4.7` AND `Storage = 64GB` AND `NFC = TRUE`. There could be more than 3 parameters to filter.

```
SELECT product_id FROM product_attributes
WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id from product_attributes 
                        WHERE attribute = 'Screen Size' AND value = '4.7')
AND product_id IN (SELECT product_id from product_attributes 
                        WHERE attribute = Storage AND value = '64GB')
AND product_id IN (SELECT product_id from product_attributes 
                        WHERE attribute = NFC AND value = 'TRUE')
GROUP BY product_id
```

If I use OR in WHERE statement I will end up having iPhone 6s, 7 and 8.

```
SELECT product_id FROM product_attributes
WHERE product_id IN (SELECT product_id from product_attributes 
        WHERE (attribute = 'Screen Size' AND value = '4.7') 
        OR (attribute = Storage AND value = '64GB') 
        OR (attribute = NFC AND value = 'TRUE')
```

So I think I've to repeat the `AND product_id IN ...` part for as many filters as I have.

I hope I'm wrong! and there is a better way to achieve this result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the INTERSECT for this.

```
SELECT product_id from product_attributes
        WHERE att_val1 = 'SS120' AND att_val2 = '1080'
INTERSECT
SELECT product_id from product_attributes
        WHERE att_val1 = 'x202' AND att_val2 = '2200'
```

https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/intersect.php

Comment: I thought MySQL doesn't have `INTERSECT` command.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/intersect.html. If has been added: INTERSECT was added in MySQL 8.0.31.

Answer (score 0):

Your example has syntax errors.  Were you hoping to get just `1001001` from that sample data?

One way:

```
( SELECT product_id from product_attributes
        WHERE att_val1 = 'x202' AND att_val2 = '2200' )
UNION ALL
( SELECT product_id from product_attributes
        WHERE att_val1 = 'SS120' AND att_val2 = '1080' )
GROUP BY product_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;
```

The best way:

```
SELECT product_id
    FROM product_attributes AS a
    JOIN product_attributes AS b  USING(product_id)
    WHERE ( a.att_val1 = 'x202'  AND a.att_val2 = '2200' )
      AND ( b.att_val1 = 'SS120' AND b.att_val2 = '1080' )
```

Both ways will benefit from `INDEX(att_val1, att_val2, product_id)`.

The schema is called EAV (Entity-Attribute-Value) or Key-Value.  It is a nuisance for writing queries and for performance.  More discussion:   http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav